# @ViewChildren and @ContentChilrden. Creating components dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-components

I have two questions.

1. I have a component `ParentComponent` inside it look like it:

`@ContentChildren(ChildComponent) contentChildren!: QueryList<ContentChilrder>`

`@ViewChildren('childName') childNames!: QueryList<ElementRef>`

Template looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<ng-container *ngFor="let contentChild of contentChildren">
  <p #childName>{{contentChild.name}}</p>
<ng-container>
```

So `childNames` is a list of of components that is used for navigation and it works
The problem appears when instead of:

```
@ContentChildren(ChildComponent) contentChildren!: QueryList<ContentChilrder>
```

use

```
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) contentChildren!: QueryList<ContentChilrder>
```

and in template:

```
<div class="container"
 <childComponent></childComponent>
 <childComponent></childComponent>
</div>
```

The name list is not generated. I was trying to subscribe to `this.contentChildren.changes | async`
but it appears to be empty even though in `console.log(this.contentChildren)` I can see the list of the components.

2. How Can I achive this while generating them dynamically with:

   `viewTemplateRef.createComponent()`

from a component tree structure that is for example a JSON or array.

Comment: Are you using `viewContainerRef.createComponent()` ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Yes. I use `viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentType, { injector: appRef.injector })`